# tomcat doesn't deliver intermediate certificate (https)

Tags: tomcat, https, certificate, openssl, keystore

I created a key and a csr on console, using the openssl executable.
Then I sent the csr to a CA and got the certificate back. Now I want to import it into tomcat.

So I created a PKCS#12 file out of my key and my certificate:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.cert -inkey mykey.pem -out key_and_cert.p12
```

and then created a keystore containing it:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass [password] -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore key_and_cert.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass [password]
```

Then I import the intermediate certificate chain.crt:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file chain.crt -keystore keystore.jks
```

Here the output of "keytool -keystore keystore.jks -list":

```
Keystore-Typ: JKS
Keystore-Provider: SUN

Ihr Keystore enthält 2 Einträge.

root, 14.11.2011, trustedCertEntry,
Zertifikatsfingerabdruck (MD5): [fingerprint]
1, 14.11.2011, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Zertifikatsfingerabdruck (MD5): [fingerprint]
```

The tomcat server.xml contains:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" URIEncoding="UTF-8" compression="on"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="/[absolute-path]/keystore.jks"
           keystorePass="[password]" />
```

When I restart tomcat, it logs no errors in catalina.out, everything seems to be ok.
But when I run firefox, it reports

```
[domain] uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.
(Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)
```

Running "openssl s_client -connect [domain]:443 -showcerts" returns

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = DE, OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = [domain]
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = DE, OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = [domain]
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 C = DE, OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = [domain]
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=DE/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=[domain]
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[certificate from mycert.cert]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=DE/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=[domain]
issuer=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 1777 bytes and written 289 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: [session-id]
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: [master-key]
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1321268519
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
```

I think tomcat doesn't deliver the intermediate certificate although it knows it. What can I do to make tomcat deliver it?

Additional information:
When importing the pkcs12 certificate, there is no certificate chain error, because the -importkeystore command doesn't checks the chain. I also tried to import the intermediate certificate first and then call -importkeystore. I got the same results.

edit:
I just tried another way by inserting the chain directly in the PKCS#12 certificate and get the following error:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -CAfile chain.pem -in mycert.cert -inkey mykey.pem -out key_and_cert.p12 -name tomcat -chain
Error unable to get issuer certificate getting chain.
```

But the chain certificate is ok:

```
$ openssl verify chain.pem
chain.pem: OK
```

Comment: do you have the root CA in your chain PEM ?

Comment: what gives you "openssl verify -CAfile chain.pem mycert.cert" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I got it working. It's not a clean solution, but it works. I added the intermediate certificate to my local /etc/ssl/certs and then called

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.key -out key_and_cert.p12 -chain
```

The resulting pkcs12 certificate I converted to jks via

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass [password] -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore key_and_cert.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass [password]
```

This resulting file seems to work now, tomcat delivers the certificate chain also to clients that don't have the intermediate certificate in their /etc/ssl/certs directory.
But I think there must also be a way without changing /etc/ssl/certs.

Comment: would you happen to have found a cleaner solution to this? I have a very similar problem.

Comment: unfortunately not but you can delete the certificate from /etc/ssl/certs afterwards

Comment: ok thank you for this tip (i actually ended up realizing that the chain I was given was somehow incomplete)

Comment: Note that you can use a PKCS#12 (.p12) file directly as a keystore in Java: use the `PKCS12` store type (`keystoreType="PKCS12"` in your Apache Tomcat connector configuration).

Comment: Note that the openssl command should be supplied with an export password, either when prompted, or with the -passout argument, as the following keytool command will not work with a blank srcstorepass.

Comment: I found that I needed to add `-certfile [intermediate cert]` to the `pkcs12 -export` command. That way, I get my own certificate plus the intermediate certificate required by certain clients.

Answer (score 14):

I had to create a CA file by finding the root cert for my issuer and then putting the intermediate cert above it in the same file.  Then I ran:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -inkey mykey.key -in mye.crt -name "tomcat" -CAfile intermediate_plus_root.crt -out key_and_cert.p12
```

Comment: I used this method but got an error: "Error unable to get issuer certificate getting chain."  So I followed some advice I found on the net and did: cat PrimaryCA.pem /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt SecondaryCA.pem > intermediate_plus_root.crt.  re-ran the above and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

There is even a more simple solution as asked for in some comments (without saving root and intermediate certs in /etc/ssl/certs)

First copy all the needed root and intermediate certificates in a folder (in our example the folder is '~/certs' and our two certificates are named 'PrimaryCA.pem' and 'SecondaryCA.pem'):

```
mkdir ~/certs
mv PrimaryCA.pem ~/certs/PrimaryCA.pem
mv SecondaryCA.pem ~/certs/SecondaryCA.pem
```

Then 'c_rehash' the folder:

```
c_rehash ~/certs
```

Now the certs folder will contain two new symlinks named regarding the following scheme '{hash-value}.{n}' where {hash-value} is an 8 symbol hash value and {n} is an integer. If that's the case for you continue to the following command which creates your .p12 using '-CApath' instead of going the long way round copying the certificates to /etc/ssl/certs:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.key -out key_and_cert.p12 -chain -CApath ~/certs
```

Finally convert it to jks as [Heinzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829568/heinzi) already perfectly described in his answer:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass [password] -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore key_and_cert.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass [password]
```

Comment: I would like to add that you need to rename the certificate inside P12 file to 'tomcat'. Iy had a name of '1' inside. I used http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html for that.

Comment: From other side you can specify that as openssl's parameter: `openssl pkcs12 -export -name "tomcat" -in cert.pem -inkey key.key -out key_and_cert.p12 -chain -CApath ~/certs`

Answer (score 6):

It works for me using APR. See [http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_APR/Native](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_APR/Native%20SSL%20Support%20-%20APR/Native)

```
  <Connector port="3573" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               SSLCertificateFile="/my/pem/encoded/certificate/file"
               SSLCertificateKeyFile="/my/pem/encoded/certificate/private_key"
               SSLPassword="yourKeyFilePassword"
               SSLCertificateChainFile="/my/pem/encoded/certificate/authorities/file"
               />
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you copy the openssl ca files into the intermediate files.

on RHEL concat following file to your issuer ca file.

```
/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```