# What is the equivalent of Unix c_rehash command/script on Linux?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am following the instructions on how to import [a certificate with its whole chain into a keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24532468/2685402).
The problem I face is that I do not have c_rehash on my system:

```
user@hostanme$ c_rehash ./certs
-bash: c_rehash: command not found
```

I have found the [-subject_hash option of openssl x509](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/x509/), but I am not sure how to use it to replicate whatever c_rehash does.

How can I hash the certificate directory without the c_rehash command/script?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

c_rehash needs "perl" for execution.
If you can not run c_rehase, try below.

use "openssl" in the Shell file

```
for file in *.pem; do ln -s "$file" "$(openssl x509 -hash -noout -in "$file")".0; done
```

Comment: Needs more quotes to be correct -- this won't work right if your certificates have whitespace in their names. Consider `ln -s "$file" "$(openssl x509 -hash -noout -in "$file")"`.

Answer (score 3):

> user@hostanme$ c_rehash ./certs
>   -bash: c_rehash: command not found

You either need to install OpenSSL (perhaps a developer version) or you need to put its `bin/` directory on path:

```
$ find /usr -iname c_rehash
/usr/bin/c_rehash
/usr/local/ssl/darwin/bin/c_rehash
/usr/local/ssl/macosx-x64/bin/c_rehash
/usr/local/ssl/macosx-x86/bin/c_rehash
```

And be sure you use the correct one. If I recall correctly, OpenSSL 0.9.8 uses MD5, while OpenSSL 1.0.0 and above use SHA1.

Answer (score 3):

The `c_rehash` command is available in the openssl-perl package

Source: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=461123
Verified on RHEL7