# How to suppress "ERROR message: short read (SSL routines, SSL routines), value: 335544539"

Tags: boost, boost-beast-websocket

Reference:
[websocket_client_sync_ssl.cpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/sync-ssl/websocket_client_sync_ssl.cpp)

```
// Read a message into our buffer
ws.read(buffer);

// Close the WebSocket connection
ws.close(websocket::close_code::normal);
```

Based on my test, the `ws.close` will spit out a warning below:

> ERROR message: short read (SSL routines, SSL routines), value:
> 335544539

Based on this post [short read](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/38), this error can be safely ignored in the end of the session. I have tried the following method to suppress the warning:

```
try
{
  boost::system::error_code close_ec;
  ws.close(websocket::close_code::normal, close_ec);
  if (close_ec)
  {
    std::cerr << "ERROR message: " << close_ec.message() << ", value: " << close_ec.value() << std::endl;
  }
}
catch(...)
{

}
```

However, the `ws.close` still prints out the warning message.

**Question**> Is there a way that I can suppress this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the ws.close still prints out the warning message.

Are you sure? It looks like that's simply coming from the line:

```
std::cerr << "ERROR message: " << close_ec.message() << ", value: " << close_ec.value() << std::endl;
```

So, you would check the value of `close_ec` and conditionally handle it: [Short read error-Boost asio synchoronous https call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63376765/short-read-error-boost-asio-synchoronous-https-call)

Also, note that some kinds of "short reads" can constitute security errors. Some of the samples have [very insightful comments about this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/timeouts.html):

```
// `net::ssl::error::stream_truncated`, also known as an SSL "short read",
// indicates the peer closed the connection without performing the
// required closing handshake (for example, Google does this to
// improve performance). Generally this can be a security issue,
// but if your communication protocol is self-terminated (as
// it is with both HTTP and WebSocket) then you may simply
// ignore the lack of close_notify:
//
// https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/38
//
// https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91435/how-to-handle-a-malicious-ssl-tls-shutdown
//
// When a short read would cut off the end of an HTTP message,
// Beast returns the error beast::http::error::partial_message.
// Therefore, if we see a short read here, it has occurred
// after the message has been completed, so it is safe to ignore it.

if(ec == net::ssl::error::stream_truncated)
    ec = {};
else if(ec)
    return;
```