# Short read errors while performing beast::http::async_read operation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Logs:

```
OnWrite(): bytes_transferred=343
OnRead(): bytes_transferred=0
OnRead(): Recv: 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
fail(): OnRead: short read
```

I am getting short read errors while performing beast::http::async_read operation.

Basically, first I perform **async_write** operation to send data to server. Then to read that data, I am performing **async_read** operation.

As the logs suggest, no bytes are read in async_read, resulting in short read error. But I wanted to understand why could it happen?

In async_read,

- Buffer used: beast::flat_buffer
- response message used: beast::http::response, I am also clearing the response message in async_read callback.

Comment: Is this happening because the buffer is getting full, causing async_read to fail?
What is the capacity of beast::flat_buffer?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing actual code, it's hard to diagnose an issue. Here's some general information that can help you understand the cause and potentially fix the issue.

`short_read` doesn't happen if there's not enough buffer, it happens when the data received doesn't satisfy the expected amount.

Short reads are normal, see [Streams, Short Reads and Short Writes](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/streams.html).

So [use the appropriate `read` primitives](https://However,%20as%20these%20could%20result%20in%20short%20writes%20or%20reads,%20an%20application%20will%20typically%20use%20the%20following%20operations%20instead) to handle expected short reads:

> Data may be read from or written to a connected TCP socket using the `receive()`, `async_receive()`, `send()` or `async_send()` member functions. However, as these could result in short writes or reads, an application will typically use the following operations instead: `read()`, `async_read()`, `write()` and `async_write()`.

The usual place where short reads crop up as an error condition is in SSL streams. OpenSSL generates the error condition¹ as [`stream_errors::stream_truncated`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__error__stream_errors.html):

> - **stream_truncated**
>
>   The underlying stream closed before the ssl stream
>   gracefully shut down.

It can naturally occur when the peer doesn't negotiate a proper shutdown.

> SSLv2 doesn't support a protocol-level shutdown, so an `eof` will be passed through as `eof` instead.

### Relevant version history

Previous releases fixed bugs related to possible short reads:

> [Fixed an ssl::stream<> bug that may result in spurious 'short read' errors.](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html#:%7E:text=Fixed%20an%20ssl%3A%3Astream%3C%3E%20bug%20that%20may%20result%20in%20spurious%20%27short%20read%27%20errors)

¹ For <v1.1 via `SSL_R_SORT_READ`

### See also

Existing posts on this site, e.g. [Short read error-Boost asio synchoronous https call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63376765/short-read-error-boost-asio-synchoronous-https-call/63412813#63412813)