# Image in report viewer doesn't show after change certificate

Tags: reporting-services, sha256

I have reporting service and web application on different server. After certificate on web application has been change to SHA256, Images that once showed on the report is never show again (Image source is from web server).

When I look upon SSRS log file, I found an error that indicate that it can't get an image

```
"Remote certificate error RemoteCertificateChainErrors..."
```

I also try to export certificate from web and install it on report server but it does not help.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What type of images are being stored? SSRS sometimes does not play well with certain types

Comment: It's JPEG image and if I don't use https url then it's work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you/they have installed certificate incorrectly? Maybe intermediate CA certificate is necessary to be provided by server for clients could validate the whole chain. It is easy to forget to provide that one.

The procedure differs from server to server. There's [solution for tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120690/tomcat-doesnt-deliver-intermediate-certificate-https). For nginx it is enough to provide concatenated certificates in one file like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[CA indermediate cert]
------END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[your domain cert]
------END CERTIFICATE-----
```

[SSRS cert installation procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372139/configure-ssrs-for-ssl), not familiar with that one. However, intermediate cert is mentioned there too.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Pictures to the PNG Format. SSRS does not play well with JPEGs